# Is it possible to use an element's undefined (auto) height in a variable / calc function?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to figure out how can I turn an element's undefined (auto) height into a variable... so that I can use it in a calc function.

I've got a two column div. The left column, is a text div with an undefined height (height: auto). The right column, is an image, but the image column's height needs to be greater than the text column's height for it to look good.

Is there a way I could set the right column's height to something like the following?:

```
/* Let's pretend this left column's height is 463px */
.column.left {
  height: auto;
}

/* And the goal for this right column's height would be 543px */
.column.right {
  height: calc(var(--col-left-height) + 80px);
}
```

So would it be possible to grab the height of the left column & turn it into a variable without setting a fixed height? I've attached an image of the actual layout I'm doing for this project, thank you so much for the help!

**Image example of the layout:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W24O2.jpg)

Comment: the layout you are showing is more than 2 columns (text + image)

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the mix up... the way I see it is that the first column on the left contains an image & text box beneath it... and the right column has a text box & image beneath. So that's why I said 2 columns, should I edit it?

Comment: What @TemaniAfif is saying is that your layout is more complicated than a typical two-column layout. Firstly, content in your right column is overlapping content in the left column. Secondly, how do you want the image in the second column to behave? If it stretches vertically, does it also need to stretch horizontally to maintain its aspect ratio? Or do you want to crop it so that the overlap stays constant? The bottom line is that you really need to edit your question to provide more detail on how you want your layout to behave.

Comment: I see, thanks for your insight! I'm a solid designer, but a total amateur when it comes to developing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to get the actual height value of an element:

```js
const leftDiv = document.querySelector(".column.left");
const rightDiv = document.querySelector(".column.right");

// get height of left column
const leftDivHeight = leftDiv.offsetHeight;

// set height of the right column: "left column + 80px"
rightDiv.style.height = leftDivHeight + 80 + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

But if you use a grid to create your columns, the default is for the grid items in those columns to stretch vertically to fit their content. So the height of the grid, and therefore the height of both columns, is determined by the column with the longest content.

What you could do in your case is to add an 80 pixel bottom padding to the item in your first column, so that means that the height of both column items will become 80 pixels higher than the content in your first column. So this essentially implements the calculation you are wanting to do.

All that then remains to be done is to give the **content inside** your second column a height of 100%. You may need to wrap this content inside an additional div in order to do this easily.